# Refresh Facebook page from within app - iframe

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

I want to refresh the complete Facebook page (not just my app within the iframe) from within my app, using javascript. How can I achieve that.?

I've tried and failed with all of the following.

```
top.location
window.location
parent.location
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
window.top.location = window.top.location
```

you can try this at browser console by pressing F12 which you can open by